# Query to get specific patterns from column

Tags: sql, plsql

One of my table column contains the below value.

```
All Files (*.*)|*.*|Bitmap (*.bmp)|*.bmp|Microsoft Word Document
(*.docx)|*.docx|GIF (*.gif)|*.gif|JPEG (*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG
(*.png)|*.png|Adobe Reader (*.pdf)|*.pdf|TIFF (*.tif)|*.tif
```

I need a query which will fetch the `bmp,docx,gif,jpg,png,pdf,tif` from above values. These values are present in brackets.

Comment: Need more info.  What version of Oracle?  Is your example 3 rows with columns separated by pipes,  Or is the entire row as shown in one column? Could there be a null value in parentheses?  Show an exact example of expected output.  What have you tried so far? That may give a clue on what you are trying to do.

Comment: What about the "All files (*.*)" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
WHERE column_with_types IN ('(.bmp)','(.docx)','(.gif)','(.jpg)','(.png)','(.pdf)','(.tif)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, given these assumptions:

- Your sample data is 3 lines
- The entire line is in one column
- You don't want the `*.*` in the first line

Try this:

```
SQL> with tbl(line_nbr, str) as (
      select 1, 'All Files (*.*)|*.*|Bitmap (*.bmp)|*.bmp|Microsoft Word Document' from dual
      union
      select 2, '(*.docx)|*.docx|GIF (*.gif)|*.gif|JPEG (*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG' from dual
      union
      select 3, '(*.png)|*.png|Adobe Reader (*.pdf)|*.pdf|TIFF (*.tif)|*.tif' from dual
    )
    SELECT line_nbr, str,
           COLUMN_VALUE AS match_nbr,
          REGEXP_SUBSTR( str ,'\(\*\.(\w*)\)', 1, COLUMN_VALUE, NULL, 1 ) AS match_value
   FROM   tbl,
          TABLE(
            CAST(
              MULTISET(
                SELECT LEVEL
                FROM   DUAL
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( str ,'\(\*\.\w*\)' )
              ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
            )
          );

  LINE_NBR STR                                                               MATCH_NBR MATCH_VALUE
---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- -----------
         1 All Files (*.*)|*.*|Bitmap (*.bmp)|*.bmp|Microsoft Word Document          1 bmp
         2 (*.docx)|*.docx|GIF (*.gif)|*.gif|JPEG (*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG                  1 docx
         2 (*.docx)|*.docx|GIF (*.gif)|*.gif|JPEG (*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG                  2 gif
         2 (*.docx)|*.docx|GIF (*.gif)|*.gif|JPEG (*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG                  3 jpg
         3 (*.png)|*.png|Adobe Reader (*.pdf)|*.pdf|TIFF (*.tif)|*.tif               1 png
         3 (*.png)|*.png|Adobe Reader (*.pdf)|*.pdf|TIFF (*.tif)|*.tif               2 pdf
         3 (*.png)|*.png|Adobe Reader (*.pdf)|*.pdf|TIFF (*.tif)|*.tif               3 tif

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Thanks to MT0 in this post for the trick to properly handle mutiple rows: [Split string by space and character as delimiter in Oracle with regexp_substr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654411/split-string-by-space-and-character-as-delimiter-in-oracle-with-regexp-substr/31656771#31656771)