# Split string by space and character as delimiter in Oracle with regexp_substr

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, split, regexp-substr

I'm trying to split a string with regexp_subtr, but i can't make it work.

So, first, i have this query

```
select regexp_substr('Helloworld - test!' ,'[[:space:]]-[[:space:]]') from dual
```

which very nicely extracts my delimiter - *blank*-*blank*

But then, when i try to split the string with this option, it just doesn't work.

```
select regexp_substr('Helloworld - test!' ,'[^[[:space:]]-[[:space:]]]+')from dual
```

The query returns nothing.

Help will be much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: What is ur expected output? only the delimiter?

Comment: Well, the result should by "Helloworld". But it's important that the delimiter will be " - ", because  i want to get the rest of the string "test" with "select regexp_substr('Helloworld - test!' ,'[^[[:space:]]-[[:space:]]]+',1,2)"

Comment: Oops sorry..I'm not getting still. Do u want to get the value before delimiter or after delimiter or the delimiter??

Comment: ok, so i have this query, and the result that i want.  "select regexp_substr('Helloworld - test!' ,'[^[[:space:]]-[[:space:]]]+'), select regexp_substr('Helloworld - test!' ,'[^[[:space:]]-[[:space:]]]+',1,2) from dual" and the results should be "Helloworld" as column 1 and "test" as column2. My problem is that i don't know how to set the delimiter to be "space - space". it works perfectly if i use only "-", but i really need "space-space" as delimiter. for example "select regexp_substr('Helloworld - test!' ,'[^-]+')from dual" work just fine, but i want to add space(blank) to the delimter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6fa6f/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST( str ) AS
          SELECT 'Hello world - test-test! - test' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Hello world2 - test2 - test-test2' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Str,
       COLUMN_VALUE AS Occurrence,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( str ,'(.*?)([[:space:]]-[[:space:]]|$)', 1, COLUMN_VALUE, NULL, 1 ) AS split_value
FROM   TEST,
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT LEVEL
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL < REGEXP_COUNT( str ,'(.*?)([[:space:]]-[[:space:]]|$)' )
           )
           AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6fa6f/2/0)**:

```
|                               STR | OCCURRENCE |  SPLIT_VALUE |
|-----------------------------------|------------|--------------|
|   Hello world - test-test! - test |          1 |  Hello world |
|   Hello world - test-test! - test |          2 |   test-test! |
|   Hello world - test-test! - test |          3 |         test |
| Hello world2 - test2 - test-test2 |          1 | Hello world2 |
| Hello world2 - test2 - test-test2 |          2 |        test2 |
| Hello world2 - test2 - test-test2 |          3 |   test-test2 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to negate the match string `'[[:space:]]-[[:space:]]'` by putting it in a character class with a circumflex (^) to negate it will not work.  Everything between a pair of square brackets is treated as a list of optional single characters except for named named character classes which expand out to a list of optional characters, however, due to the way character classes nest, it's very likely that your outer brackets are being interpreted as follows:

- `[^[[:space:]]` A single non space non left square bracket character
- `-` followed by a single hyphen
- `[[:space:]]` followed by a single space character
- `]+` followed by 1 or more closing square brackets.

It may be easier to convert your multi-character separator to a single character with regexp_replace, then use regex_substr to find you individual pieces:

```
select regexp_substr(regexp_replace('Helloworld - test!'
                                   ,'[[:space:]]-[[:space:]]'
                                   ,chr(11))
                    ,'([^'||chr(11)||']*)('||chr(11)||'|$)'
                    ,1 -- Start here
                    ,2 -- return 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. match
                    ,null
                    ,1 -- return 1st sub exp
                    )
  from dual;
```

In this code I first changed `-` to `chr(11)`.  That's the ASCII vertical tab (VT) character which is unlikely to appear in most text strings. Then the match expression of the regexp_substr matches all non VT characters followed by either a VT character or the end of line.  Only the non VT characters are returned (the first subexpression).

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, this will help you. Currently you are getting output as `Helloworld`(with space at the end). So i assume u don't want to have space at the end. If so you can simply use the space in the delimiter also like.

```
select regexp_substr('Helloworld - test!' ,'[^ - ]+',1,1)from dual;

OUTPUT
Helloworld(No space at the end)
```

As u mentioned in ur comment if u want two columns output with `Helloworld` and `test!`. you can do the following.

```
select regexp_substr('Helloworld - test!' ,'[^ - ]+',1,1),
       regexp_substr('Helloworld - test!' ,'[^ - ]+',1,3) from dual;

OUTPUT
col1         col2
Helloworld   test!
```

Comment: Yes, it kinda works, but there is a problem : if the string is "Hello World - test" (with space between Hello and World), then column1 gets "Hello", and column two "-". It splits the string by the first space it finds, not space-space. Maybe i wasn't very clear from the beginning,sorry for that . So if my string is "Hello World - test", the result should be "Hello World" and "test" :) thank you very much for the efforts though!!!

Answer (score 0):

Slight improvement on MT0's answer.  Dynamic count using regexp_count and proves it handles nulls where the format of [^delimiter]+ as a pattern does NOT handle NULL list elements. More info on that here: [Split comma seperated values to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464275/split-comma-seperated-values-to-columns/31464699#31464699)

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
  2    select ' - Hello world - test-test! -  - test - ' from dual
  3  )
  4  SELECT LEVEL AS Occurrence,
  5         REGEXP_SUBSTR( str ,'(.*?)([[:space:]]-[[:space:]]|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1 ) AS split_value
  6  FROM   tbl
  7  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(str, '[[:space:]]-[[:space:]]')+1;

OCCURRENCE SPLIT_VALUE
---------- ----------------------------------------
         1
         2 Hello world
         3 test-test!
         4
         5 test
         6

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Using `CONNECT BY` in the main query will work fine for a single row input but will give erroneous results if you try to perform that query on multiple input rows. I've updated my answer with a version that will support multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION field(i_string            VARCHAR2
                                ,i_delimiter         VARCHAR2
                                ,i_occurance         NUMBER
                                ,i_return_number     NUMBER DEFAULT 0
                                ,i_replace_delimiter VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2     IS
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Function Name.......: FIELD
  -- Author..............: Dan Simson
  -- Date................: 05/06/2016 
  -- Description.........: This function is similar to the one I used from 
  --                       long ago by Prime Computer.  You can easily
  --                       parse a delimited string.
  -- Example.............: 
  --  String.............: This is a cool function
  --  Delimiter..........: ' '
  --  Occurance..........: 2
  --  Return Number......: 3
  --  Replace Delimiter..: '/'
  --  Return Value.......: is/a/cool
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---                                    
  v_return_string  VARCHAR2(32767);
  n_start          NUMBER := i_occurance;
  v_delimiter      VARCHAR2(1);
  n_return_number  NUMBER := i_return_number;
  n_max_delimiters NUMBER := regexp_count(i_string, i_delimiter);
BEGIN
  IF i_return_number > n_max_delimiters THEN
    n_return_number := n_max_delimiters + 1;
  END IF;
  FOR a IN 1 .. n_return_number LOOP
    v_return_string := v_return_string || v_delimiter || regexp_substr    (i_string, '[^' || i_delimiter || ']+', 1, n_start);
    n_start         := n_start + 1;
    v_delimiter     := nvl(i_replace_delimiter, i_delimiter);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN(v_return_string);
END field;


SELECT field('This is a cool function',' ',2,3,'/') FROM dual;

SELECT regexp_substr('This is a cool function', '[^ ]+', 1, 1) Word1
      ,regexp_substr('This is a cool function', '[^ ]+', 1, 2) Word2
      ,regexp_substr('This is a cool function', '[^ ]+', 1, 3) Word3
      ,regexp_substr('This is a cool function', '[^ ]+', 1, 4) Word4
      ,regexp_substr('This is a cool function', '[^ ]+', 1, 5) Word5
  FROM dual;
```

Comment: Some explanation would be great.

Comment: I frequently have the need to parse some text in order to extract a subset of the text.  Sometimes the text has delimiters such as a period: The.File.Name.is.THIS.created.on.20160506  Where all I really want is the word THIS.  I could call my FIELD function with this statement: SELECT field('The.File.Name.is.THIS.created.on.20160506','.',5,1) FROM dual;

Comment: Grab the function and try it. You can use it to parse any text easily.  I looked at some of the great examples in this post.  They all work great, but I'd never be able to remember all those crazy regexp bits and pieces: '([^'||chr(11)||']*)('||chr(11)||'|$)'