# SQL Concatenate strings across multiple columns with corresponding values

Tags: sql, oracle, db2, concatenation, substr

I'm looking for a way to achieve this in a SELECT statement.

FROM

```
Column1    Column2    Column3
A,B,C      1,2,3      x,y,z
```

TO

```
Result
A|1|x,B|2|y,C|3|z
```

The delimiters don't matter. I'm just trying to to get all the data in one single column. Ideally I am looking to do this in DB2. But I'd like to know if there's an easier way to get this done in Oracle.
Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in the first place

Comment: Oracle and db2 - very unusual combination...

Comment: Ideally, yes. But there's are use cases where normalizing all the data is expensive.
And just because storing comma separate values in a column isn't ideal, doesn't mean the question is bad and needs to be downvoted  :)

Comment: @jarlh It is not a combination that I'm looking for. I have the flexibility to query either databases which have the same table.

Comment: To me it seems a simple use case of **SUBSTR**, **INSTR** and **concatenation**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

- **SUBSTR**
- **INSTR**
- **||** concatenation operator

It would be easy if you break your output, and then understand how it works.

```
SQL> WITH t AS
  2    ( SELECT 'A,B,C' Column1, '1,2,3' Column2, 'x,y,z' Column3 FROM dual
  3    )
  4  SELECT SUBSTR(column1, 1, instr(column1, ',', 1) -1)
  5    ||'|'
  6    || SUBSTR(column2, 1, instr(column2, ',', 1) -1)
  7    ||'|'
  8    || SUBSTR(column3, 1, instr(column1, ',', 1) -1)
  9    ||','
 10    || SUBSTR(column1, instr(column1, ',', 1, 2) +1 - instr(column1, ',', 1),
 11                       instr(column1, ',', 1) -1)
 12    ||'|'
 13    || SUBSTR(column2, instr(column2, ',', 1, 2) +1 - instr(column2, ',', 1),
 14                       instr(column2, ',', 1) -1)
 15    ||'|'
 16    || SUBSTR(column3, instr(column3, ',', 1, 2) +1 - instr(column3, ',', 1),
 17                      instr(column3, ',', 1) -1)
 18    ||','
 19    || SUBSTR(column1, instr(column1, ',', 1, 3) +1 - instr(column1, ',', 1),
 20                       instr(column1, ',', 2) -1)
 21    as "new_column"
 22  FROM t;

new_column
-------------
A|1|x,B|2|y,C
```

---

On a side note, you should avoid storing delimited values in a single column. Consider **normalizing** the data.

From **Oracle 11g** and above, you could create a **VIRTUAL COLUMN** using the above expression and use it instead of executing the **SQL** frequently.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this using INSTR and SUBSTR:

```
   select 
   substr(column1,1,instr(column1,',',1)-1) || '|' ||
   substr(column2,1,instr(column2,',',1)-1) || '|' ||
   substr(column3,1,instr(column3,',',1)-1) || '|' ||
   ',' ||
   substr(column1 ,instr(column1 ,',',1,1)+1,instr(column1 ,',',1,2) - instr(column1 ,',',1)-1) || '|' || 
   substr(column2 ,instr(column2 ,',',1,1)+1,instr(column2 ,',',1,2) - instr(column2 ,',',1)-1) || '|' || 
   substr(column3 ,instr(column3 ,',',1,1)+1,instr(column3 ,',',1,2) - instr(column3 ,',',1)-1) || '|' || 
   ',' ||
   substr(column1 ,instr(column1 ,',',1,2)+1) || '|' || 
   substr(column2 ,instr(column2 ,',',1,2)+1) || '|' || 
   substr(column3 ,instr(column3 ,',',1,2)+1) 
   from yourtable
```

Answer (score 1):

i tried some thing. just look into [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cff67/2)
first i created a table called **t_ask_test** and inserted the data based on the above question. Achieved the result by using the **string functions**

sample table

```
 create table t_ask_test(column1 varchar(10), column2 varchar(10),column3 varchar(10));
```

inserted a row

```
insert into T_ASK_TEST values ('A,B,C','1,2,3','x,y,z');
```

the following query will be in dynamic way

```
select substr(column1,1,instr(column1,',',1,1)-1)||'|'||substr(column2,1,instr(column1,',',1,1)-1)||'|'||substr(column3,1,instr(column1,',',1,1)-1) ||','||
 substr(column1,instr(column1,',',1,1)+1,instr(column1,',',1,2)-instr(column1,',',1,1)-1)||'|'||substr(column2,instr(column2,',',1,1)+1,instr(column2,',',1,2)-instr(column2,',',1,1)-1)||'|'||substr(column3,instr(column3,',',1,1)+1,instr(column3,',',1,2)-instr(column3,',',1,1)-1) ||','||
 substr(column1,instr(column1,',',1,2)+1,length(column1)-instr(column1,',',1,2))||'|'||substr(column2,instr(column2,',',1,2)+1,length(column2)-instr(column2,',',1,2))||'|'||substr(column3,instr(column3,',',1,2)+1,length(column3)-instr(column3,',',1,2)) as test from t_ask_test;
```

output will be as follows

```
     TEST
---------------
A|1|x,B|2|y,C|3|z
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dynamic number of entries for each row then:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1abd93/8)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( Column1, Column2, Column3 ) AS
          SELECT 'A,B,C', '1,2,3', 'x,y,z' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'D,E', '4,5', 'v,w' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH ids AS (
  SELECT t.*, ROWNUM AS id
  FROM   TEST t
)
SELECT LISTAGG(
                   REGEXP_SUBSTR( i.Column1, '[^,]+', 1, n.COLUMN_VALUE )
         || '|' || REGEXP_SUBSTR( i.Column2, '[^,]+', 1, n.COLUMN_VALUE )
         || '|' || REGEXP_SUBSTR( i.Column3, '[^,]+', 1, n.COLUMN_VALUE )
       , ','
       ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY n.COLUMN_VALUE ) AS value
FROM   ids i,
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT LEVEL
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= GREATEST(
               REGEXP_COUNT( i.COLUMN1, '[^,]+' ),
               REGEXP_COUNT( i.COLUMN2, '[^,]+' ),
               REGEXP_COUNT( i.COLUMN3, '[^,]+' )
             )
           )
           AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       ) n
GROUP BY i.ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1abd93/8/0)**:

```
|             VALUE |
|-------------------|
| A|1|x,B|2|y,C|3|z |
|       D|4|v,E|5|w |
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. However this wont work in DB2

Answer (score -1):

Its very simple in oracle. just use the concatenation operatort ||.
 In the below solution, I have used underscore as the delimiter

```
select Column1 ||'_'||Column2||'_'||Column3 from table_name;
```

Comment: Not really. The corresponding values need to be concatenated.
With your above statement, the result would be "A,B,C_1,2,3_x,y,z"

Comment: What do you mean by corresponding values need to be concatenated.
If the table is like
  A  1  x
  B  2  y
  C  3  Z
my query would make it
 A_1_x
 B_2_y
 C_3_Z

Comment: Look at the "Result" in the question.

Comment: If the table is like
  A  1  x,
  B  2  y,
  C  3  Z,
my query would make it
 A_1_x,
 B_2_y,
 C_3_Z,

Comment: The contents of the column are a comma separated list. Imagine there is only one row in each column and the value is 'A,B,C' for Column 1

Comment: In that case you have to use regexp_sbstr ...look at this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654411/split-string-by-space-and-character-as-delimiter-in-oracle-with-regexp-substr